# Connection refused when running TCP client

Tags: python, c, linux, network-programming, tcpclient

I'm working on a lab project that requires me to write a TCP client in C and a TCP server in Python.

The issue I'm having right now with the TCP client is that every time I try to connect the client to the server which is also running on my PC, there is a "Connection refused" error and the `errno` is 111. (The TCP server works just fine since every time I type in `localhost:5566` on web browser, the server received some information)

By the way, I'm running all the code on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04.6 installed.

The C code for the client and the Python code for the server is attached.

TCP client code (in C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define SERVER_IP   "127.0.0.1"   /* Dotted-decimal representation of server's IP address */
#define SERVER_PORT 5566              /* Server's port number */
#define BUF_SIZE    1024              /* Size of buffer used for data transmission */

static int client_fd;                  /* Client socket file descriptor */
static struct sockaddr_in server_addr; /* Server socket address struct */

static void client_init() {
    /* Creates a client socket descriptor */
    client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* Handles socket error */
    if (client_fd == -1) {
        perror("socket error");
        exit(errno);
    }

    /* Sets fields of Server socket address struct */
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                   /* Protocol family (IPv4) */
    server_addr.sin_port = SERVER_PORT;                 /* Port number in network byte order (big-endian) */
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP); /* IP address in network byte order (big-endian) */

    /* Establishes a connection to the server and handles connect error */
    if (connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("connect error");
        exit(errno);
    }
}

void main() {
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    file = fopen("./client.txt", "r+");

    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen error");
        exit(errno);
    }

    client_init();

    while (fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        // Sends data to the server and handles sendto error
        if (sendto(client_fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr))== -1) {
            perror("sendto error");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Clears buffer
        bzero(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

TCP server code (in Python)

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER_IP     = "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_PORT   = 5566
SERVER_ADDR   = (SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
PACKET_SIZE   = 1024

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(SERVER_ADDR)


def client_handler(client, client_addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {client_addr}\n")

    while True:
        # Reads at most PACKET_SIZE bytes data, blocks when no packet is received
        packet = client.recv(PACKET_SIZE)

        # Writes file from the packet received
        with open('./server.txt', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(packet)

def server_init():
    print(f"Listening on {SERVER_PORT}")
    server.listen()
    
    while True:
        # Everytime a new client is connected to the server, create a new thread dedicated to that client
        # Every thread will block until the connection to that client is established
        client, client_addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client, client_addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTION] {threading.active_count() - 1}\n")


print("Starting server...")
server_init()
```

Comment: Are you running both the client and server processes on the same VM? By the way, TCP does not have clients or servers, it creates bidirectional connections between peers. The client/server concept is an application concept, not for TCP.

Comment: You may need to use htons() when setting the port number in the C code.

Comment: Also, typically, a server would listen on address INADDR_ANY, not the loopback address.

Comment: `listen` typically wants an argument (e.g. `listen(5)`) to specify the [max] number of clients that may connect to the server at any given time. I don't know what the default arg value is for python, but you might want to use an explicit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Unix-style socket networking code uses what is known as "network byte order", which is also known as "big-endian". But many common desktop/embedded platforms (e.g. x86 and ARM) use "little-endian" byte ordering.

When you set up a socket in your C code, you need to convert your port number from the native, little-endian, "host" byte order, to "network" order. To do that, you can use the htons() function, which is a shortening of host-to-network-short().

i.e. you want this:

```
server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
```

It seems that the python sockets library handles this kind of thing under the hood, so you don't need to worry about it there.